# R: Viewing the observations that were included in my random sample

Tags: r, random

Part of an assignment that I'm working on requires that I take a 10% sample from the data in my df:

```
sample <- sample(NROW(toyota.df), round(.1*NROW(toyota.df)))
```

...this runs, and I then attempt to view the sample:

```
View(sample)
```

...and all I get is this:

[image: screenshot of my view]

...is there a way for me to view the observations that make up my sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sample` contains the row indices of your data. You need to use it to subset your dataframe.

```
sample_inds <- sample(NROW(toyota.df), round(.1*NROW(toyota.df)))
sample_df <- toyota.df[sample_inds, ]
View(sample_df)
```

`sample` is a function in R so it is better if you don't name the variables with that name.